How to change Y axis scale for Multi line chart in iOS using SwiftUI
I am creating multi-line chart using Apple's Chart framework in SwiftUI. In that I have 2 lines with different range of data. So, I want to set different scale for both of lines. Here is my code, in that I am able to draw 2 lines for a single chart but I am not able to assign scale ranges for Y axis for both lines.
struct ChartPlot: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: UUID = .init()
    let x: Int
    let y: Int
}

struct SwiftUIView1: View {
    let arr1 = [
        ChartPlot(x: 2, y: 1),
        ChartPlot(x: 4, y: 5),
        ChartPlot(x: 6, y: 4),
        ChartPlot(x: 8, y: 8),
        ChartPlot(x: 10, y: 7)
    ]
    let arr2 = [
        ChartPlot(x: 1, y: 20),
        ChartPlot(x: 2, y: 60),
        ChartPlot(x: 4, y: 45),
        ChartPlot(x: 7, y: 70),
        ChartPlot(x: 9, y: 40)
    ]
    var body: some View {
        Chart {
            ForEach(arr1) { plot in
                LineMark(
                    x: .value("", plot.x),
                    y: .value("", plot.y),
                    series: .value("", "Value1"))
            }
            .foregroundStyle(.yellow)

            ForEach(arr2) { plot in
                LineMark(
                    x: .value("", plot.x),
                    y: .value("", plot.y),
                    series: .value("", "Value2"))
                .foregroundStyle(.red)
            }
        }
        .chartYScale(domain: 0...100, type: .linear)
        .chartYAxis {
            AxisMarks(position: .leading, values: .automatic) {
                AxisValueLabel()
                    .foregroundStyle(.orange)
                AxisTick()
                    .foregroundStyle(.orange)
            }
        }
        .chartYScale(domain: 0...10, type: .linear)
        .chartYAxis {
            AxisMarks(position: .trailing, values: .automatic) {
                AxisValueLabel()
                    .foregroundStyle(.green)
                AxisTick()
                    .foregroundStyle(.green)
            }
        }
    }
}

As you can see in the data, 1 set is having range from 0 to 10 and another having 0 to 100, So, I want to use different scale for both lines (orange and green).
But I'm getting correct code.
